# Can you get plugin configuration from a POM using aether?

Tags: java, xml, maven, aether

I have a requirement to read plugin configurations in Java. I have used the aether library to get run time dependencies, compile time dependencies etc. But can I use aether to read plugin configurations based in the pom file?

Something like this

```
<properties>
  <servicePort>8080</servicePort>
  <adminPort>8081</adminPort>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <configuration>
        <myConfig>
          <somePropName>someProp</somePropName>
          <portMappings>
            <someProp>${servicePort}</someProp>
            <someProp-admin>${adminPort}</someProp-admin>
          </portMappings>
        </myConfig>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to be able to resolve

```
some-Prop 8080
some-prop-admin 8081
```

from this mechanism

Currently I fetch the compile tie dependencies like this

```
Dependency dependency = new Dependency(new DefaultArtifact(
                    coordinate), COMPILE);
CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
collectRequest.setRoot(dependency);

collectRequest.addRepository(this.aetherSession
        .getRemoteRepository());
DependencyNode node = this.aetherSession
        .getRepoSystem()
        .collectDependencies(this.aetherSession.getRepoSession(),
                collectRequest).getRoot();
DependencyRequest dependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest();
dependencyRequest.setRoot(node);
result = this.aetherSession
        .getRepoSystem()
        .resolveDependencies(this.aetherSession.getRepoSession(),
                dependencyRequest).getArtifactResults();
FinalResult.addAll(result);
```

Comment: Can you post your current code to fetch compile time dependencies? Are you writing a Maven plugin or an external application?

Comment: This is a java application, I want to read the plugin config from a pom using aether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a simpler way, but you can use the Aether API to resolve the POM artifact you're interested in, and then build a Maven model from it with the Model Builder API.

First of all, if the coordinates to your artifact isn't to the POM artifact, you need to convert them to the POM artifact by creating a new `DefaultArtifact` with the same GAV, but of type `"pom"`. To resolve the artifact, you can invoke [`resolveArtifact`](http://sonatype.github.io/sonatype-aether/apidocs/org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem.html#resolveArtifact(org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystemSession,%20org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactRequest)) on the repository system, and retrieve the result with [`getArtifact()`](http://sonatype.github.io/sonatype-aether/apidocs/org/sonatype/aether/resolution/ArtifactResult.html#getArtifact()).

Once you have the resolved artifact, you can use [`maven-model-builder`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-model-builder/) to build the Maven model from the artifact's file. The `ModelBuilder` can be created with [`DefaultModelBuilderFactory.newInstance()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/building/DefaultModelBuilderFactory.html#newInstance()) factory method.

For artifacts that have a parent POM, a [`ModelResolver`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/resolution/ModelResolver.html) needs to be set on the request to build a Model. However, the only usable implementation with Aether, which is `DefaultModelResolver`, is package-private inside `maven-aether-provider` so we need to use the Reflection API to construct it. It needs to be injected components that are retrieved with the `serviceLocator` returned by `MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator()`. This needs to be the same locator with which the Aether session was constructed.

```
DefaultArtifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact(coordinate);
Artifact pomArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(artifact.getGroupId(), artifact.getArtifactId(), "pom", artifact.getVersion());

ArtifactRequest request = new ArtifactRequest(pomArtifact, Arrays.asList(aetherSession.getRemoteRepository()), null);
pomArtifact = aetherSession.getRepoSystem().resolveArtifact(session, request).getArtifact();

ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new DefaultModelBuilderFactory().newInstance();
ModelBuildingRequest buildingRequest = new DefaultModelBuildingRequest();
buildingRequest.setPomFile(pomArtifact.getFile());
buildingRequest.setProcessPlugins(true);
buildingRequest.setValidationLevel(ModelBuildingRequest.VALIDATION_LEVEL_MINIMAL);

Constructor<?> constr = Class.forName("org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver").getConstructors()[0];
constr.setAccessible(true);
ModelResolver modelResolver = (ModelResolver) constr.newInstance(session, null, null,
        serviceLocator.getService(ArtifactResolver.class),
        serviceLocator.getService(VersionRangeResolver.class),
        serviceLocator.getService(RemoteRepositoryManager.class), request.getRepositories());
buildingRequest.setModelResolver(modelResolver);

Model model = modelBuilder.build(buildingRequest).getEffectiveModel();

Xpp3Dom pluginConfiguration = (Xpp3Dom) model.getBuild().getPluginsAsMap().get("com.company.group:my-plugin").getConfiguration();
Xpp3Dom myConfig = pluginConfiguration.getChild("myConfig");
System.out.println(myConfig.getChild("somePropName").getValue()); // prints "someProp"
```

By default, the model builder isn't configured to process plugins, so we need to invoke `setProcessPlugin(true)`. Once the effective model is obtained, the configuration is contained in a `Xpp3Dom` object that you can navigate with the help of `getChild(name)`, to get the named child XML element, and `getValue()` to get the value of the XML element.

Comment: Trying to test the above code, although it fetches the jar not the pom

Comment: @user_mda I have included the code to fetch the POM not the JAR. Look at `Artifact pomArtifact` and `buildingRequest.setPomFile(pomArtifact.getFile());`.

Comment: yes I copied the same code, but it fails at parsing it, since pomArtifact.getFile() gives me a jar

Comment: The pom artifact is constructed with `new DefaultArtifact(artifact.getGroupId(), artifact.getArtifactId(), "pom", artifact.getVersion());`, so it should not reference the JAR, the 3rd parameter is the extension, which is `"pom"` here (and it didn't in the tests I've made). What are you using for `coordinate`?

Comment: Yes Thats what I expected it to do, I am using the following to assign coordinates -- String.format("%s:%s:%s", groupID, artifactID, version);

Comment: Can you post `System.out.println(artifact)` and `System.out.println(pomArtifact)`? They should not be the same.

Comment: You re right in that they are not the same , artifact is the jar om artifact is the pom but pomArtifact.getFile gets the jar not the pom.xml

Comment: Ooh I see I made a small mistake in the code I posted! Sorry for that! It should be `ArtifactRequest request = new ArtifactRequest(pomArtifact, ...)` and not `ArtifactRequest request = new ArtifactRequest(artifact, ...)` I just edited the mistake.

Comment: Thank you! That gets me the pom although I am getting a different error   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no model resolver provided, cannot resolve parent POM com.group.id:artifactID:0.8-SNAPSHOT for POM ${appGroupId}:artifactID:[unknown-version] ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123642/discussion-between-tunaki-and-user-mda).